# Excel, using match index, and if statement

Tags: excel

My issue is that I have an excel file. The file requires me to analyze 4 columns. 
This is the data:

- F is the column for the in-active and active
- B is for the name being compared
- G is the column with a bunch of names
- H is the column with the dates

Given the status as in-active, or active, beside the city name, i am required to match it with the other city column if it is Active. If it is active, then display the date.

I tried to implement this formula:

```
=IF(INDEX(F:F, MATCH(B2,$G:$G))="Active",INDEX(H2:H1683, MATCH(B2,G2:G1683,0)),"n/a")
```

but it seems to display for active and inactive.

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a mock up of the data and expected output in tabular form.  It will make it easier to understand what you want.

Comment: you can try changing the first MATCH to `MATCH(B2,$G:$G,0)` but without a mock up of the data it is hard to do anything but guess.

Comment: As per your request I have added in a sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xlookup to search for multiple criteria.

`=XLOOKUP("active"&B2,$F$2:$F$14&$G$2:$G$14,$H$2:$H$14,"na",0)`

Or, you can use an alternative form using boolean logic:

`=XLOOKUP(1,($F$2:$F$14="active")*($G$2:$G$14=B2),$H$2:$H$14)`

See https://exceljet.net/formula/xlookup-with-multiple-criteria for a tutorial on searching with multiple criteria.

Comment: I am matching status, as if in-active I do not need a date.

Comment: Added some alternative forms that may be easier to work with in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMIFS:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/SUMIFS(H:H,F:F,"Active",G:G,C2)),"n/a")
```

This assumes that only one date per Name/Status combo exists.

[image]

---

With the new Dynamic Array formulas:

```
=@FILTER($H$2:$H$7,($F$2:$F$7="Active")*($G$2:$G$7=C2),"n/a")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution

```
=IF(INDEX($F3:$F1684,MATCH($B3,$G3:$G1684,0))="Actual",INDEX($H2:$H1684,MATCH(B3,G2:G1683,0)))
```